# How get this xaml to work from app.xaml

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, app.xaml

I made this UpButton.xaml file by converting it from an .ai-file that our graphics guys made but i just can't get it to work.
I was thinking of making this some sort of template/style for buttons, but our buttons are made up from rectangles and not the button object.

I've been fiddling with this since last Thursday, googled and tried everything I found but it just won't work.

we like to have this in a seperate xaml file as a 'Resource', then add that into app.xaml and let this paint all rectangles throughout the entire application.
The application we're building are supposed to use xaml and as little C# coding as possible.

Can anyone help me get this thing to work?

thx for letting me know about the code Sample :)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <DrawingBrush x:Key="UnnamedObject0" Stretch="Uniform">
        <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
            <DrawingGroup>
                <DrawingGroup.Children>
                    <GeometryDrawing Geometry="F1 M 141.781,503.813C 140.737,503.813 139.891,504.659 139.891,505.703L 139.891,524.601C 139.891,525.645 140.737,526.491 141.781,526.491L 160.679,526.491C 161.723,526.491 162.568,525.645 162.568,524.601L 162.568,505.703C 162.568,504.659 161.723,503.813 160.679,503.813L 141.781,503.813 Z ">
                        <GeometryDrawing.Brush>
                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.499992,-1.61488e-005" EndPoint="0.499992,1">
                                <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFD1D3D4" Offset="0"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="1"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </GeometryDrawing.Brush>
                    </GeometryDrawing>
                    <DrawingGroup ClipGeometry="F1 M 0,0L 793.701,0L 793.701,1122.52L 0,1122.52L 0,0 Z ">
                        <DrawingGroup.Children>
                            <GeometryDrawing Geometry="F1 M 139.891,505.703C 139.891,504.659 140.737,503.814 141.781,503.814L 160.679,503.814C 161.723,503.814 162.568,504.659 162.568,505.703L 162.568,524.6C 162.568,525.644 161.723,526.491 160.679,526.491L 141.781,526.491C 140.737,526.491 139.891,525.644 139.891,524.6L 139.891,505.703 Z ">
                                <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                    <Pen Thickness="1.33333" LineJoin="Round" Brush="#FFA7A9AC"/>
                                </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                            </GeometryDrawing>
                        </DrawingGroup.Children>
                    </DrawingGroup>
                    <GeometryDrawing Geometry="F1 M 144.048,506.081C 143.005,506.081 142.159,506.927 142.159,507.969L 142.159,522.333C 142.159,523.377 143.005,524.223 144.048,524.223L 158.412,524.223C 159.455,524.223 160.301,523.377 160.301,522.333L 160.301,507.969C 160.301,506.927 159.455,506.081 158.412,506.081L 144.048,506.081 Z ">
                        <GeometryDrawing.Brush>
                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.499951,1.00003" EndPoint="0.499951,-3.36442e-006">
                                <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFE6E8E8" Offset="0"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="1"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </GeometryDrawing.Brush>
                    </GeometryDrawing>
                    <GeometryDrawing Geometry="F1 M 144.645,515.816L 147.521,515.816L 147.521,521.56L 151.24,521.56L 154.939,521.56L 154.939,515.816L 157.813,515.816L 151.219,508.743L 144.645,515.816 Z ">
                        <GeometryDrawing.Brush>
                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.499986,1.00003" EndPoint="0.499986,5.23812e-005">
                                <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF50C400" Offset="0"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF91F456" Offset="1"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </GeometryDrawing.Brush>
                    </GeometryDrawing>
                    <DrawingGroup ClipGeometry="F1 M 0,0L 793.701,0L 793.701,1122.52L 0,1122.52L 0,0 Z ">
                        <DrawingGroup.Children>
                            <GeometryDrawing Geometry="F1 M 151.24,521.56L 147.521,521.56L 147.521,515.815L 144.646,515.815L 151.218,508.743L 157.814,515.815L 154.938,515.815L 154.938,521.56L 151.24,521.56 Z ">
                                <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                    <Pen Thickness="1.33333" LineJoin="Round" Brush="#FF076F00"/>
                                </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                            </GeometryDrawing>
                        </DrawingGroup.Children>
                    </DrawingGroup>
                </DrawingGroup.Children>
            </DrawingGroup>
        </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
    </DrawingBrush>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: Post it, and I'll edit it so it's correct. But you can just copy it all into the textbox, select it, and then click the button that looks like '1010'.

Comment: To post a code sample just paste the xmal into the edit window, highlight the section that is code and press the Code Sample button.  which will format it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put it in a style like:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
        <Setter Property="Fill">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DrawingBrush Stretch="Uniform">
                    <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                        <DrawingGroup>
                            <DrawingGroup.Children>
                                <GeometryDrawing Geometry="F1 M 141.781,503.813C 140.737,503.813 139.891,504.659 139.891,505.703L 139.891,524.601C 139.891,525.645 140.737,526.491 141.781,526.491L 160.679,526.491C 161.723,526.491 162.568,525.645 162.568,524.601L 162.568,505.703C 162.568,504.659 161.723,503.813 160.679,503.813L 141.781,503.813 Z ">
                                    <GeometryDrawing.Brush>
                                        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.499992,-1.61488e-005" EndPoint="0.499992,1">
                                            <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FFD1D3D4" Offset="0"/>
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="1"/>
                                            </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                    </GeometryDrawing.Brush>
                                </GeometryDrawing>
                                <DrawingGroup ClipGeometry="F1 M 0,0L 793.701,0L 793.701,1122.52L 0,1122.52L 0,0 Z ">
                                    <DrawingGroup.Children>
                                        <GeometryDrawing Geometry="F1 M 139.891,505.703C 139.891,504.659 140.737,503.814 141.781,503.814L 160.679,503.814C 161.723,503.814 162.568,504.659 162.568,505.703L 162.568,524.6C 162.568,525.644 161.723,526.491 160.679,526.491L 141.781,526.491C 140.737,526.491 139.891,525.644 139.891,524.6L 139.891,505.703 Z ">
                                            <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                                <Pen Thickness="1.33333" LineJoin="Round" Brush="#FFA7A9AC"/>
                                            </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                        </GeometryDrawing>
                                    </DrawingGroup.Children>
                                </DrawingGroup>
                                <GeometryDrawing Geometry="F1 M 144.048,506.081C 143.005,506.081 142.159,506.927 142.159,507.969L 142.159,522.333C 142.159,523.377 143.005,524.223 144.048,524.223L 158.412,524.223C 159.455,524.223 160.301,523.377 160.301,522.333L 160.301,507.969C 160.301,506.927 159.455,506.081 158.412,506.081L 144.048,506.081 Z ">
                                    <GeometryDrawing.Brush>
                                        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.499951,1.00003" EndPoint="0.499951,-3.36442e-006">
                                            <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FFE6E8E8" Offset="0"/>
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="1"/>
                                            </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                    </GeometryDrawing.Brush>
                                </GeometryDrawing>
                                <GeometryDrawing Geometry="F1 M 144.645,515.816L 147.521,515.816L 147.521,521.56L 151.24,521.56L 154.939,521.56L 154.939,515.816L 157.813,515.816L 151.219,508.743L 144.645,515.816 Z ">
                                    <GeometryDrawing.Brush>
                                        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.499986,1.00003" EndPoint="0.499986,5.23812e-005">
                                            <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FF50C400" Offset="0"/>
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FF91F456" Offset="1"/>
                                            </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                    </GeometryDrawing.Brush>
                                </GeometryDrawing>
                                <DrawingGroup ClipGeometry="F1 M 0,0L 793.701,0L 793.701,1122.52L 0,1122.52L 0,0 Z ">
                                    <DrawingGroup.Children>
                                        <GeometryDrawing Geometry="F1 M 151.24,521.56L 147.521,521.56L 147.521,515.815L 144.646,515.815L 151.218,508.743L 157.814,515.815L 154.938,515.815L 154.938,521.56L 151.24,521.56 Z ">
                                            <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                                <Pen Thickness="1.33333" LineJoin="Round" Brush="#FF076F00"/>
                                            </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                        </GeometryDrawing>
                                    </DrawingGroup.Children>
                                </DrawingGroup>
                            </DrawingGroup.Children>
                        </DrawingGroup>
                    </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                </DrawingBrush>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Then in your App.Xaml include the resource as:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/RectStyle.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

By not setting the x:Key on the `<Style>` Resource will modify all Rectangles in your application with the specified fill...
If you want more styles for your rectangles you need to add the x:Key="RectStyle1" property to the `<Style>` and specify which style the rectangle needs to use as this:

```
<Rectangle Style="{StaticResource RectStyle1}" />
```

Have fun :)

Comment: Yep that worked, Think i tried all of this but I can't have :P

Thanks alot